# How can i use EOF in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

in c / c++ i use EOF like

```
int n;

while( scanf("%d",&n) != EOF ){

printf("%d",n);

}
```

## now how can i use EOF in Python ?

please give me the same code using python

Comment: Don't try to write C in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this in python:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```